# Is Unity 2D ever coming back?

Tags: unity-2d

I have some computers which only operate on Unity 2D because of their hardware, so I rely on Unity 2D and Ubuntu 12.04. In the future I could use Gnome Shell, I could use Unity 3D via llvmpipe (which is real slow) or even LXDE, but I just love Unity 2D and its speed. Is it ever coming back for newer Ubuntu releases?

Answer (score 3):

The only way unity 2d will ever come back, is as part of petition, etc.

It is such a shame to see it go, maybe a community version might come about?

Answer (score 1):

Unity 2D is definitely deprecated now in favour of standard Unity via llvmpipe. It's not coming back.

Performance of llvmpipe may, however, continue to improve over time. I couldn't guarantee that it will ever match the speed of Unity 2D, but time will tell.